# How to transfer SPL tokens using client side javascript

Tags: solana-program

I've been looking for examples of people using @solana/spl-token in the browser by bundling it with browserify or rollup or webpack but haven't been able to get any of them to work. I'm not convinced I need @solana/spl-token library but when I try to create a transfer instruction myself (using the web3.js package) it gets rejected.

```
/* setup connection, connect to phantom wallet, set up the variables for wallet keypairs and the mint address ... can assure you there is no issue with any of this 
*/
// ... 
// ...

empty_transaction.feePayer = window.solana.publicKey;

const instruction = new solanaWeb3.TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [
        { pubkey: source, isSigner: false, isWritable: true }, // Source account
        { pubkey: destination, isSigner: false, isWritable: true }, // Destination account
        { pubkey: owner, isSigner: true, isWritable: true }, 
    ],
    programId: token_program_id,
    data: new Uint8Array([3, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
});

// add the instruction
empty_transaction.add(transferInstruction);

const blockhashInfo = await clusterConnection.getRecentBlockhash();

const recentBlockhash = blockhashInfo.blockhash;

empty_transaction.recentBlockhash = recentBlockhash;

await empty_transaction.partialSign(signingKeypair);

console.log("everything up until here works, sendAndConfirmTransaction throws an error")
await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(clusterConnection, empty_transaction, [signingKeypair]);
```

So I'm asking for anyone with a working example of executing a transfer of spl tokens client side, I don't care how it's done whether you use web3 and build the instruction or spl-token and let the library handle everything, as long as it works. All the recommendations to browserify *do not work*, if you've been able to browserify spl-token please tell me how you did it. I'm pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that you've been having issues with the `spl-token` JS package.

Your approach here is correct overall, you need to sign the transaction with `owner` though.

And this won't impact the correctness, but you should pass the owner account as `isWritable: false`.

After that, perhaps there's something wrong with the `source` or `destination` accounts (ie not initialized to the correct mint, not enough tokens)